# Howto override WPF childcontrols style if a style already is set?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have a simple childcontrol that already have a style defined for a element in the childcontrol.
Can I change that style of that element from the parent control?

If I dont set the style in the childcontrol I can override it from the parent control, but I cant seem to get it to work when the style is set.

I can't change the code in the childcontrol.

The example childcontrol:

```xml
    <UserControl
    x:Class="TestingThemes.ChildControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestingThemes"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DesignHeight="450"
    d:DesignWidth="800"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="aw" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button
            Width="100"
            Height="50"
            Content="Kalle Anka"
            <!-- If I remove the style I can override it from parent control -->
            Style="{DynamicResource aw}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The parentcontrol:

```
 <Grid>
    ...            
    <local:ChildControl>
        <local:ChildControl.Resources>
            <!--<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource local:ResourceKey=aw}" TargetType="Button">-->
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
        </local:ChildControl.Resources>
    </local:ChildControl>
   
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but you must change the location of the initial `Style`.
The XAML engine will traverse the logical tree to lookup `StaticResource`/`DynamicResource` resources for an element (e.g., `Button`) starting locally, with the local `ResourceDictionary`.

This means, you want the default `Style` that is defined inside the `UserControl` to be found at the very end of the lookup route - after any potential custom styles that are intended to override the default `Style`. To accomplish this, you must move the `Style` either to *App.xaml* or *Generic.xaml*.
Additionally, the reference must be `DynamicResource` in order to defer the lookup to the moment the logical tree is composed. The overriding `Style` can be defined anywhere up the route towards the tree root.

Since *Generic.xaml* provides a different name scope, you would have to define a unique static (global in terms of the XAML name scopes) `ComponentResourceKey` which you would have to use as the style's `x:Key` value (in case you plan to move the default Style to the *Generic.xaml* file).

Because of the aforementioned XAML resource lookup behavior, creating a custom `Control` is always prefereable over a `UserControl` when you plan to make the control customizable (like in your case). The default `Style` of a custom `Control` is located in the *Generic.xaml* by default, thus you would have never ran into your current issue.

**ChildControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl>
  <Grid>
    <Button Style="{DynamicResource aw}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**App.xaml**
The last lookup location before the *Generic.xaml*. If a `Style` with the same key was not found yet, the `Style` found in `App.xaml` will be applied.

```
<Style x:Key="aw" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
</Style>
```

**ParentControl.xaml**

```
<ChildControl>
  <ChildControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="aw" TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
  </ChildControl.Resources>
</ChildControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation. But that means that if i cant change the code of the childcontrol, there isnt anything i can do. The childcontrol that i want to restyle isn't built in this way where the style is defined app/genric.xaml :(

Comment: Then the control is poorly designed. What you can do is to wait for the application to be loaded. If you know the element tree of the control, you can traverse its visual tree to lookup the Button (or element of interest) and override the Style by assigning a new local style. If you don't know the element tree, you can use tools like Snoop to inspect it. This is not graceful but your last option - apart from creating an improved control from scratch.  When you create controls that encapsulate functionality, then UserControl is never a good choice.